# Ubuntu - how to create relative file path shortcuts

Tags: file, ubuntu, path, shortcut

I have a problem with file shortcuts on Ubuntu (in particular, on the 16.04 release).

I have folder containing my project (let's call it MyProject), and that folder has a subfolder inside, called html (generated with Doxygen, if that matters), that contains a very large amount of files. One of them, "index.html", is the only thing I have to manually open as all the other ones are mostly elements used by it. What I have done is thus to create a file shortcut and cut-paste it into the parent folder (i.e. MyProject folder), so that I can avoid browsing through all those files every time (or having to search for it through the file explorer).

My problem is that I need my project to be independent from my machine, since I am working at it with other people. If one of them downloads the MyProject folder, everything works fine apart from the index.html file shortcut, because after double-clicking it, it tries to locate the file by looking for the same file path as the one on my computer, which is of course different. Is there a smart way to solve this issue? I would prefer to avoid scripts if possible, since I assume there is actually a way to make a "more flexible" file shortcut.

Comment: Do your teammates work on Linux too, or does anyone use Windows?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can confirm that everyone is using Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path of the symbolic link as relative, as explained in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/146231/how-do-i-create-a-relative-symbolic-link-in-linux#146232). I've tried it in my machine (SO: Linux Mint Sylvia) and works just fine.

**Example:**

1. I have two folders `/Projects/ProjectA` and `/Projects/ProjectB`, both of which contain a relative `html/index.html` (generated by Doxygen, as in your case).
2. I create a relative symlink in `ProjectA`

```
cd /Projects/ProjectA
ln -s ./html/index.html my_link # Note the './' in the source path
```

3. If I use `xdg-open my_link` my browser opens `/Projects/ProjectA/html/index.html` correctly.
4. Then I move *that same link* to the other directory.

```
cd /Projects/ProjectB
mv /Projects/ProjectA/my_link .
```

5. And if I run `xdg-open my_link` it opens `/Projects/ProjectB/html/index.html`
6. I've not tested it in different machines, but as the moved link doesn't try to open `/Projects/ProjectA/html/index.html` I'm pretty shure this should do.

The link is relative to its own directory, so even if you open it from other location, it will open the same file always (until the link itself is moved or copied).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. At first I do not know why I got some downvotes here on stack, so I quickly accepted to give up on this. So thank you twice indeed! But if you too think that I made something wrong (bad formatting, not stating that I tried enough beforehand or that I did some research on stakoverflow prior to posting), please tell me.

Comment: @Jetboy In my opinion the question lacks some newlines (its a big text block). Also, its always good to state what you have tried/read so far, to inform others of your own research.